# Screen Resolution in Adobe AIR

Tags: air

How to automatically set screen resolution for phone in ADOBE AIR.
And what is this codes stands for?

```
public static function get screenResolutionX():Number
public static function get screenResolutionY():Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the screen resolution for a device -- it's read-only (`Capabilities.screenDPI`)

`Capabilities.screenResolutionX` and `Capabilities.screenResolutionY` are the width and height, in pixels, of the device, when Air first runs.

Comment: Najwa: did this answer your question? If so, would appreciate if you can mark it, thanks.